# JPA and JSON operator native update query?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

I'm trying to make this query work in JPA:

```
@Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = " UPDATE topic_answer SET " +
            " tpa_media_info = jsonb_set(tpa_media_info, '{relativePath}'::text[], to_jsonb(:relativePath::text))) " +
            " WHERE tpa_id =:answerId ")
    void updateAnswerRelativePath(@Param("answerId") UUID answerId, @Param("relativePath") String relativePath);
```

It works perfectly with postgresql but when I integrate it with JPA, I get the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [relativePath], expecting one of [answerId, relativePath::text]

Comment: ':relativePath::text' in your query causes JPA to expect a parameter named 'relativePath::text' to be input - you are instead giving it a 'relativePath'. Not sure what you were doing in PostgreSQL to pass in parameters, but I'd suggest removing the ::text since it is a string, not a jSON

Comment: Yes Thanks That works I did this jsonb_set(tpa_media_info, '{relativePath}', to_jsonb(:relativePath))